# Haskell: Change a list of 100 numbers to 10 lists of 10 numbers?

Tags: list, function, haskell, functional-programming, purely-functional

In Haskell, how does one change a list of x numbers into n lists of n numbers?

The first sublist would have numbers first to tenth, second list 11th to 20th...

myFunction :: [Int] -> [[Int]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `chunksOf` function in [`Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html):

```
chunksOf 2 [0, 1, 2, 3] -- [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Alternatively, we already have `splitAt` in `prelude`, with which `chunksOf` can be implemented with ease:

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n [] = []
chunksOf n xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as : chunksOf n bs
```

Comment: note that in older versions of ghc you have to 'cabal install split' (i think before 7.6)

Comment: Why oh why isn't an equivalent in Prelude? I don't want o depend on the split package if I'm writing something quick & small.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a little simpler to read with take and drop and requires no libraries.

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf _ [] = []
chunksOf n xs = take n xs : chunksOf n (drop n xs)
```